# Export user conversations data from IBM Watson Assistant (Conversation)?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

Can we export conversation data which is shown in **improve** section of IBM Watson Assistant? It is basically conversation analytics.

*Downloading that data to any format will be fine*

Answer (score 2):

You can use the API to obtain the logs: [List log events in a workspace](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/assistant#list-log-events-in-a-workspace)

This allows you to export the logs and save them in the format you want. The API supports some filters to only retrieve specific entries. The documentation for IBM Watson Assistant has a section on [learning from conversations](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/logs.html#deploy_id) and discusses logs.

Comment: is there any other approach? other than this ?

Comment: There are some non-IBM tools that use that API. I wrote one https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool/ But the API is the only way to download.